# Use GridView to display data from two different entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got two entities, joined by DashboardId in the .edmx file

How do I create a GridView that will display data from both tables where the DashboardId is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Linq join will return you a flat object that contains what ever fields you want from each object, then you can use the results to bind to your datagrid.

Comment: This is the method i've been working on..  Where I am getting a bit stuck is in adding the option to delete a record.  How do I do that?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the id in your flattened recordset to look up the item in your objectcontext and delete from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can write code for the join on OnQueryCreated event. Please have a look at the article here for a working code:

http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1584